# CSS: Setting up a flex grid that takes 2 differ sizes of items

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with the grid I am setting up.  I am trying to set up a grid that takes 2 different size boxes and can wrap them appropriately but they aren't wrapping properly. I want the margin to stay the same but the content to fit appropriately up to their max width.

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box1 {
   background: green;
   height: 20px;
   max-width 30px;
   flex: 1;
   margin: 3px;
}

.box2 {
   background: pink;
   height: 20px;
   max-width 50px;
   flex: 1;
   margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="box1"></div>
   <div class="box2"></div>
   <div class="box1"></div>
   <div class="box1"></div>
   <div class="box2"></div>
   <div class="box2"></div>
   <div class="box2"></div>
   <div class="box1"></div>
   <div class="box2"></div>
   <div class="box1"></div>
   <div class="box1"></div>
   <div class="box1"></div>
   <div class="box2"></div>
   <div class="box1"></div>
   <div class="box2"></div>
   <div class="box1"></div>
   <div class="box1"></div>
   <div class="box1"></div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="box1"></div>
   <div class="box2"></div>
   <div class="box2"></div>
   <div class="box1"></div>
   <div class="box1"></div>
   <div class="box1"></div>
</div>
```

Example of desired look:

> ```
>      -------------------------------------
>     |                                    |
>     | [ BOX1 ] [ BOX1 ] [     BOX2    ]  |
>     | [ BOX1 ] [     BOX2    ] [ BOX1 ]  |
>     | [ BOX1 ] [ BOX1 ] [ BOX1 ] [ BOX1 ]|
>     |                                    |
>     _____________________________________
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Doing this with flex box would be a headache, it's much easier to do using css grid, here:

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, 25% );
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box1 {
   background: green;
   height: 20px;
   width 25%;
   flex: 1;
   margin: 3px;
}

.box2 {
   background: pink;
   height: 20px;
   width 50%;
   flex: 1;
   grid-column: auto / span 2;
   margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="box1"></div>
   <div class="box1"></div>
   <div class="box2"></div>
   <div class="box1"></div>
   <div class="box2"></div>
   <div class="box1"></div>
   <div class="box1"></div>
   <div class="box1"></div>
   <div class="box1"></div>
   <div class="box1"></div>
   </div>
```